# Nested indented output with a recursion method

Tags: java, recursion

I have an assignment to use a recursive method to print out multiple lines, each line having 3 more spaces in front of it than the previous. Here is a picture of the desired output (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKz9z.png).

This is the code I have so far:

```
public class Prog6d {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(printFactorial(input));
    }

    //Calculates the factorial
    public static int printFactorial(int input) {
        if (input == 1) {
            return 1;
        }
        System.out.println("factorial(" + input + ")");
        System.out.print("   ");
        return input*printFactorial(input-1);
    }
}
```

I know how to make the spaces appear correctly using a for-loop, but I have no idea how to do this with recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do this often.  I have two basic methods, related:

1. Make a global string variable **indent**, initialized to the empty string.  On entry to the function, lengthen it by three spaces.  When you leave, shorten it to the previous length.
2. Add a parameter **indent**.  The initial call is with an empty string; each recursion concatenates three spaces to the value.

In each case, I just use **indent** as the first thing printed on the line.

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: I would recommend approach number two over approach number one, because you’ll save yourself a lot of headache debugging your programs if you avoid global variables. If you make your calls tail-recursive, the parameterized version should be equally efficient.