# Convert Excel Table data to Parent Child Relation

Tags: excel, vba, data-structures, ms-office

I am trying to to convert excel data in parent child relation. I am having huge amount of data, so it will take time to convert it manually. for example:

```
state->District->City
```

and want to convert in

```
ID  Name  Parent_ID
1   state   0 
2  district  1
```

any code or reference will be help and appriciated

thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you add a small example of your data to your question (or if you can't post your actual data then at least something *representative* of your data). It's pretty tough to help without knowing what your working with, but there is probably a quick solution (likely [Pivot](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) or [Unpivot](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8112776+unpivot).) Also see "[ask]" and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: ^^ Sample data will go a **long** way here. I would show at least 10 or 15 strings that you have. Ideally, there will be a  consistent delimiter to make use of. As is, your question is not answerable without a ton of *dangerous* and *wasteful* assumptions.

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/q/50095791/56778  answers your question.